# Is it possible to store graph databases within another database of any form?

Tags: database, graph

I was wondering if it is possible to store graph related data (for example a guitar node having various other nodes of data connected to it like specs and description) inside another database?

Imagine a graph inside a block in a tabular database. Or a key of `guitar` which has various nodes connected with a `value` pair. If possible, what are the performance limitations, drawbacks and etc.?

Answer (score 0):

you can take most business scenarios and model them in multiple ways so yes, in theory, you could define one solution that uses a graph DB and another solution that uses a relational DB.

Whether you can actually model the business scenario for specific DB types would be down to the details of the requirements, as would the pros and cons.

I'm afraid your question is too general to provide an answer that gives any specifics on performance limitations, drawbacks, etc.

Comment: In the question I stated that I want to combine two different database models. For example storing a graph database inside a tabular. In this scenario I'm trying to figure out the different performance aspects. Am I being too general hehe?

Comment: Hi - (depending slightly how you define it) a database is self-contained entity consisting of an engine plus data structured in a way that the engine can use; therefore the statement "storing a graph database inside a tabular" is meaningless - it's like saying storing an Oracle DB in a SQL Server DB. You can store the same data in 2 different types of DB but you would have to re-structure it to met the requirements of each DB engine. Even if you could lift-and-shift data from a graph to a tabular DB, for example, there would be no point as the tabular DB wouldn't be able to use it effectively